# Reading a portion of the file defined by 2 end points in nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, filesystems, html5-filesystem

I am a newbie on nodeJs, but i am loving it already.
I have the following data.xml file.

```
<data>
 <student>
  <age>16</age>
  <name>Bill</name>
 </student>
 <teacher>
  <age>33</age>
  <name>Priyanka</name>
 </teacher>
</data>
```

I want to read the details of the student from this file.
I explored fs.readStream, fs.readFile but some how not being able to get it right. Readline might be a solution(i am not sure), but what if the xml is not formatted well?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't parse invalid xml- so fix it. Then you can use xml2js (install by running `npm install xml2js`) node module and this code:

```
var fs= require('fs');
var parseString = require('xml2js').parseString;

fs.readFile('./data.xml', 'utf8', function read(err, data) {
    if (err) {
        throw err;
    }

    parseString(data, {trim: true}, function (err, result) {
        if (err){
            throw err;
        }
        console.dir(result);
    });
});
```

If you won't fix the xml, the code will throw an exception of course (closing tag of teacher's age is invalid). 
You should check the encoding of your xml file,for brevity  I assumed utf8.

Comment: Thanks @RLaaa. Really appreciate that. What are the options if the data is a json file?

Comment: json is easier, you would not use the xml parsing module of course and you would probably want to parse the json to an object. Replace the parseString call with var obj=JSON.parse(data);
Notice that parse can throw execption if the json is invalid. See here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/parse